# Handling Add Tasks intent, siri kit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, siri, sirikit

Although I believe I am following the right instructions for the handle function of the intent handler; everything finishes as it should (the data is saved), I send the success code back from the handle function and yet when the request is finished, Siri always displays "Continue in app". Anyone had a similar problem and know the solution? Here is the code I implement before exiting the handler, written in swift:

```
let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INAddTasksIntent.self))
    let response = INAddTasksIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: userActivity)
    completion(response)
```

Comment: I should clarify Siri displays "Sorry you'll need to continue in the app." not just Continue in app

Comment: I should also add that the same thing happens to me using the same code in the Create Note handler

Comment: Try deleting your app from the simulator and reinstalling it

Comment: Tried that, no luck unfortunately

Comment: Getting even stranger as I tried pretty much the same code in the handler for the Payments domain and it worked fine. You hardly have to return to the app regardless in the notes and lists domain??

Answer (score 1):

For those concerned, the problem is solved by attaching the target task list and the tasks to be added to the response as follows:

```
    let responseCode = INAddTasksIntentResponseCode.success

    let response = INAddTasksIntentResponse(code: responseCode,
                                               userActivity: nil)

    var addedTasks:[INTask] = []
    for title in intent.taskTitles!{
        let newTask = INTask(title: title, status: .notCompleted, taskType: .completable, spatialEventTrigger: nil, temporalEventTrigger: nil, createdDateComponents: nil, modifiedDateComponents: nil, identifier: nil)

        addedTasks.append(newTask)
    }

    response.modifiedTaskList = intent.targetTaskList!
    response.addedTasks = addedTasks
    completion(response)
```